# Flutter should single widget be excluded from parent column/row

Tags: flutter, widget

I have a custom widget which 90% of the times is only one single widget but depending on some conditions it can be 2 or 3 which should fit vertically.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
  List<Widget> children = [];

  // Main widget
  children.add(widget.child);

  // Condition
  if (condition1)
    children.add(otherWidget);

  // Condition
  if (condition2)
    children.add(anotherWidget);

  return Column(children: children);
}
```

Since 90% of the time it is only a single widget, should I remove the column?

```
  return children.length > 1 ? Column(children: children) : children.first;
```

I haven't seen that logic anywhere. What is more common is keeping the `column` and using the conditions inside:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)
{
  return Column(children: [
   widget.child,
  if (condition1)
    otherWidget,
  if (condition2)
    anotherWidget,
  ]);
}
```

I prefer the latter, but should I bother with the fact there will be most likely an unnecessary column build?

(btw this widget is a sample child for a `ListView` with lots of children and inside it there will be stateful widgets which need to keep their state.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use the Column and widgets within wrapped inside a visibility widget (so you don't need an extra widget if not necessary)

```
Column(
  children: [
    child,
    Visibility(
      visible: condition,
      child: anotherWidget,
    )
    Visibility(
      visible: condition,
      child: anotherWidget,
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: The main issue is whether to make an unnecessary column or not. Your solution worsens the situation and adds 2 more unnecessary widgets to the problem. Thanks for the effort though.